# Is "to be conjugate" is an equivalence relation?

Tags: field-theory, equivalence-relations, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Let denote $P_x$ the minimal polynomial of $x$ over a field $K$. We say that $x$ and $y$ are conjugate if $P_x(y)=0$.

Is "to be conjugate" is an equivalence relation ?

The question behind this question is can $x$ and $y$ be conjugate, $y$ and $z$ be conjugate and $x$ and $z$ not conjugate ? In other term, if $P_x(y)=0$ and $P_y(z)=0$ does $P_x(z)=0$ or not necessarily ?

I don't think it's true, but I can't find any example. Any idea ?

Comment: It is true. What's the relationship between $P_x$ and $P_y$ given that $P_x(y)=0$?

Comment: In general conjugation will be an equivalence relation. Usually you first see this in groups where you develop the class equation.

Comment: Ok great :-) Then the term "conjugate" make sense since all this time I heard it :-) Thank you very much.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog: Why in general ? Sometimes it is not ?

Comment: In all the instances I've come across, conjugation gives an equivalence relation.

Comment: If you know any Galois theory, the result above is really saying that elements of the Galois group must send roots of a minimal polynomial to other roots of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @SamWeatherhog: I'm studying it in this moment. You have made a nice comparaison, and in fact, by your remark it's obvious. Thank you :-)

Comment: This is a bad definition. The good definition is that $x$ and $y$ have the same minimal polynomial, and then it's clear that this is an equivalence relation. You don't need to know any Galois theory to see this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the minimal polynomial of $x$ is the same as the minimal polynomial for $y$ then $z$ is a root of this polynomial and transitivity holds. But a minimal polynomial is irreducible (by minimality - easily seen because we are over a field so there are no zero divisors) so this is straightforward.

---

See comments: this depends actually on an assumption about the context. I was taking $x$ to lie in an algebraic extension of the ground field. But the wording of the question admits other possibilities.

Comment: "because we are over a field" should be "because we are _in_ a field". Minimal polynomials of matrices over a field can very well be reducible. Actually the OP does not say where $x$ and $y$ live, only that their minimal polynomials are over a field $K$. Though one might induce from the wording and the `field-theory` tag that they are supposed to be elements of another field.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Fair point - that is an ambiguity in the question. "Over" is used in the question. I agree if you go to matrices over a field you do get zero divisors and different phenomena.